# Ranger File Manager - Open in Preview.APP - macOS

Tags: macos, terminal

I've manage to map `oo` keys to open image with `Preview.app` in `Ranger` by adding this to `rc.conf` :

```
map oo shell open %s
```

Is there anyway to make it easier just by highlighting the `filename` in `Ranger` and using a return key to open in Preview.app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map <Enter> shell open %s`

Tested in macOS 10.14

Answer (score 0):

I added `ext pdf, has open,     X, flag f = open "$@"` to my rifle.conf for pdfs. I think you can adapt this to images.

UPD `mime ^image, has open,       X, flag f = open -- "$@"` worked.